# Подключение одного класса php, внутри другого.

Tags: ооп, php

Доброго времени суток, хотелось бы узнать как правильно использовать один класс в содержании другого. 
**Пример:** Есть класс для работы с дб. Есть класс для работы с юзерами, как в классе работы с юзерами использовать класс работы с бд?
*Всем благодарен за помощь.*

Comment: Можно воспользоваться внедрением зависимостей (dependency injection), что бы разделить классы друг от друга по интерфейсам: http://habrahabr.ru/post/64061/

Comment: Статья не плохая, но что-то мне подсказывает, что ТС только начинает постигать ООП, а вы его сразу в дебри :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так что не устраивает?:

```
class WorkWithDB {
    public function someMethodOfWorkWithDB() {}
}

class WorkWithUsers {
    private $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new WorkWithDB;
    }
    public function someMethodOfWorkWithUsers() {
        $this->db->someMethodOfWorkWithDB();
    }
}
```